# Accessing an objects value by fieldName in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, reflection

I know I could do something like this:

```
data class Foo(val bar: String)

val foo = Foo("bar")

foo::class.java.getDeclaredField("bar").let {  it.trySetAccessible(); it.get(foo) }
```

For this tho I need to use `class.java.getDeclaredField("bar")` and other Java things like `trySetAccessible()` and `get`.

Is it possible to do this in a more Kotlin way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kotlin reflection doesn't have functions like `getDeclaredField()`. Instead, it has functions returning collections, like `getMemberProperties()`, and you can use the Iterable extension functions to find what you need. Pass an instance of the class as the first parameter of the getter/setter you want to use.

```
    val value = Foo::class.memberProperties
        .first { it.name == "bar" }
        .also { it.isAccessible = true } // if it's not visible
        .getter(foo)
```

Note to do this without casting you need to use `Foo::class` instead of `foo::class` because the latter is a `Class<out Foo>` so the getters it returns are not usable due to variance.

But if you're using reflection, you may not know the class you're working with, in which case you'd have to cast the returned property before using it.

```
    val value = foo::class.memberProperties
        .first { it.name == "bar" }
        .also { it.isAccessible = true }
        .let { it as KProperty1<in Any, *> }
        .getter(foo)

// or

    val value = (foo::class as KClass<in Any>).memberProperties
        .first { it.name == "bar" }
        .also { it.isAccessible = true }
        .getter(foo)
```

Comment: is it possible to also edit the value in the field? Like to make it mutable and then edit the value and set it to immutable again?

Comment: Kotlin reflection does not have any way to access fields, so it can't be used to do this. It only knows of properties, and doesn't even have a way to detect if those properties utilize a backing field or not. So you have to use Java reflection to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with Kotlin reflection like this:

```kotlin
val prop = (foo::class as KClass<Foo>).memberProperties.single { it.name == "bar" }
println(prop.get(foo))
```

Note that contrary to Java, you can't use this technique to set the value of read-only field (`val`). The reason is: in Kotlin we don't really deal with fields, but with properties. And property is a getter and optionally a setter. If there is no setter then there is nothing really to invoke. `val` may not be backed by a field, it may not hold any value at all. In such case it would not make sense to even consider setting the value of a property.

Of course, Kotlin reflection API could provide optional access to fields if property is backed by one, but right now I believe there is no representation for fields in public API.